# How can you assign a character value to a integer type variable in C?

Tags: c, char, int

In C,

```
...
int num = 'a';
...
```

My question is simple. How can you assign a character such as '0', 'a', 'b' to an integer type variable without getting any type error in C language?

Comment: @AnshDavid Wrong answer. There is no conversion whatsoever in the question, and “casting” means using an explicit conversion.

Comment: @AnshDavid Type casting is when I write `(type)value` in order to cast `value` into type `type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For historical reasons (mostly), character constants are of type `int` in C.

But even if they weren't, an  initialization like

```
int num = 'a';
```

or an assignment like

```
num = 'a';
```

would still be perfectly legal. A value of any numeric type may be assigned to a variable of any (other) numeric type, and the value will be implicitly converted (which may involve a change of representation and/or a risk of overflow).

And `char`, along with its relatives `unsigned char` and `signed char`, are numeric types, specifically integer types.

Answer (score 4):

The character is only a representation of an integer value. For example, `'0'` can be written as `0x30` or `48`, `'a'` is an alternative for `0x61` or `97`, etc.

So the assignment is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can. In C character constant is of type `int`. Which makes it a bit different with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) and [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character). Every character is a number, actually everything in computing is numbers, just some of them (depending on type and value) are rendered like characters.

For storing characters variable type should be `char` or `wchar_t` but it can be any other type, because all of them are just a numbers in memory.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry I read the question wrong and wrote a comment, my bad) `----->`

```
int main()
{

    int num = 'a';
    printf("%c", num);
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
a
```