# Assign a Number to a char variable in C?

Tags: c, char, int

I'm planning to assign a number datatype into the char variable.
The code would be something like this :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned u;

ushort getRandomNumber(){
    return (ushort)(rand() % 9);
}

ushort getASCII(char Char) {
    return (ushort)Char;
}

char getRandomChar() {
    ushort chance = (rand() % 2) + 1;
    const ushort aASCII = 97 , zASCII = 122 , AASCII = 65 , ZASCII = 89;
    if(chance == 1)
        return (char)(aASCII + (rand() % (zASCII - aASCII)));
    else
        return (char)(AASCII + (rand() % (ZASCII - AASCII)));
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    ushort size;
    puts("Enter password size : " );
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%i" , &size);
    if(size >= 4) {
    char Password[size + 1];
        for(ushort i = 1 ; i <= size ; ++i){
            ushort chance = (rand() % 2) + 1;
                if(chance == 1)
                    Password[i] = getRandomChar();
                else
                    Password[i] = getRandomNumber();

        }
    printf("%s" , Password);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else {
        puts("Error. Try again");
    }
}
```

It will not return any error but it will print the character that matches the ASCII code. So this code won't be the right one.

The original code is a random password generator that isn't very good and secure one I know it. the random numbers show up as ASCII characters in the output.

I searched on Google but no useful result. Only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400018/how-can-you-assign-a-character-value-to-a-integer-type-variable-in-c) but it is the reverse process.
What is the command/algorithm for that?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The problem here is that I'm assigning the int to the array of char that has chars that I don't want to show as numbers.

Comment: `printf("%d", b)` will do...

Comment: Puts does not print numbers. It prints strings. You need to printf with the %hhd format

Comment: @EugeneSh Then I would need to add more details for clarification.

Comment: if you thought that copying an `int` to a `char` would help printing it, I guess you have learned now that that's not the right way... So if that was the only reason for having a `char` get rid of it because the assignment may overflow and produce unexpected results.

Comment: You don't assign anything to array of char. There is no arrays in your code.

Comment: The fact is that this code isn't the original It seems I must edit the code too to get rid of the downvote you gave me

Comment: @JonnyHenly Well, the latest edit should tell you that this isn't that simple.

Comment: @JonnyHenly haven't done programming for two years. I forgot some facts.

Comment: What output do you expect from the updated code? Btw. for `puts()` the array had to be NUL terminated

Comment: All chances are you're looking for **sprintf**.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt The original array has one more node with a null assigned.
Don't try to find errors in the code it isn't the original.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do with `int a` though. *The original array has one more node with a null assigned.* Then please [edit] your question to include the actual code so we can stop shooting in the dark.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Does that really matter ? It is creating a char array mixed of random numbers and chars and prints the array which is a string.

Comment: Yes it matters, you asked this question 25 minutes ago and multiple solutions to multiple problems have been suggested, none of which answer your actual question, which is still unknown.

Comment: Do you expect this program to output "e123d4"?

Comment: @dbush Exactly. Yet everyone wants the original code.

Comment: Thank you for including the actual code, +1. I think Vikas Gautam's answer below is one way of doing what you're looking for. Be careful though, you should keep track of how many char's and int's are in the array and where they are. Otherwise your array length vs. array entries count will be off.

Comment: @Programmer This is why we ask for a [mcve].  Now that we've seen your whole code, it's apparent what you're trying to do, and it's also apparent that what you originally asked isn't really the solution to your problem.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for the downvote now.

If what I was searching wasn't the good way to achieve my goal it doesn't mean an unclear or unuseful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you're actually doing is populating a string with either letters or single digits, you don't actually want to store the numbers themselves but the ASCII codes for the digits.

You can do that as follows:

```
ushort getRandomNumber(){
    return '0' + (ushort)(rand() % 10);
}
```

Note the use of a character constant instead of a "magic number" for the ASCII code.  You can make a similar change when getting a character:

```
char getRandomChar() {
    ushort chance = (rand() % 2) + 1;
    if(chance == 1)
        return 'a' + (rand() % ('z'- 'a' + 1));
    else
        return 'a' + (rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1));
}
```

The C standard guarantees that the digits for 0 - 9 are consecutive in whatever character encoding is used.  That guarantee does **not** exists however for letters.

You can simplify the logic a bit more by creating an array of all the characters you want to use and index into that array to get a given random character:

```
char characters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for(ushort i = 1 ; i <= size ; ++i){
        Password[i] = characters[rand() % sizeof(characters)];
    }
    Password[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Would your last code be a secure one?

And the last line is what I need to understand.

Comment: @Programmer Not really, since neither version is using a cryptographically secure random number generator, but it's more clear and concise.

Comment: cryptographically secure random number generator ? do you have any reference to this expression?

Comment: @Programmer It's a random number generator where it's more difficult to guess the values.  The `rand` function doesn't qualify, but OpenSSL's `RAND_bytes` does.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want type conversion from int to char, but since we can convert only single digit to char at a time, so we have to extract all digits and store it in a string and then reverse string to get answer.

hope this code will give you some ideas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 10000
int main(void){
    int a = 12233;
    char b[max];             // Create a char array of max size
    int i=0,j;
    while(a)
    {
        int rem = a%10;            // since we can only convert single int digit to char use loop to extract digits
        b[i] = rem + '0';          // and convert into char
        i++;
        a = a/10;
    }
    b[i] = '\0';                  // don't forget to insert '\0' to make it string
    for(i=0,j=strlen(b)-1;i<=j;i++,j--)        // now we have char array like 21, so we have to reverse it
    {
        char temp = b[i];
        b[i] = b[j];
        b[j] = temp;
    }

    puts(b);                       // print string
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **printf()** would help, puts() is used to print strings to the console

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    int a = 12;
    char b = a;
    printf("%d",b);
    return 0;
}
```